# ionic2 image upload efficiently

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic2 Tranfer plugin to upload image. image is uploading to cloud successfully but it take much time to upload. how can speed up image upload in ionic2 application. Can any one help ?

```
const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
fileTransfer.upload(filename, url, options).then(data => {
       this.presentToast('Image succesful uploaded.');
}, err => {
    this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the file size of the file you are uploading and compared it to your network speed?

For example, if you try to upload a full sized image from your phone it can easily be 4MB. Let's assume your network's upload is 500 kbit/s. This would result in over a minute of upload time.

There is no way to reduce that time other than either reducing the file size or making your connection faster.

So depending on your needs, you probably want to reduce the file size by either reducing the dimensions or the quality of your image.

Answer (score 0):

IN case you are not interested in the full Image, then 
You can use Image cropping feature at client side before it gets updated.